# Отследить конец commit в fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, callback, fragment-transaction

Добавляю фрагмент с анимационным переходом.
Переход длиться в районе 1 секунды.

```
fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
fragmenttransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.alpha_start, R.anim.alpha_end);
fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentArrayList.get(indexSlide));
fragmenttransaction.commit();
```

Есть кнопка которая переключает фрагменты, как слайдер. Если я часто нажимаю на кнопку, пока анимацинный переход идет, то возникает ошибка.

Я хочу сделать следующее, при нажатии на кнопку, она становиться не активной, как только закончился анимационный переход, на кнопку опять можно нажать.
Не нашел метода куда можно повесить callback функцию по завершению commit.

В интернете не нашел. Есть только как отследить внутри самого фрагмента что анимация появления фрагмента закончена. Мне это не подходит.

Comment: можно блочить кнопку на время = длительность анимации

Comment: Это не совсем корректно. Разве нет метода который срабатывает как только commit выполнился полностью?!